# slideDown() slideUp() reversal

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am after is a comand for doing the same as *slideDown() slideUp()*, but to work from the opposite direction.

So basicaly, slideUp() opens and slideDown() closes the div.

If it was only two div's , this would not be needed, but it will be with five or more in the same space.

If not possible, the only other option is if it is possible to "move" the div in the stack.
So on close, the div moves location in the html to above the one that has just opened. That way the illusion is still there.

EDIT:
From looking, though as sagested, the "Accordion" jQuery function was not what I was after, but a sub-class looks promissing.

If anyone into jQuery can help, would it be possible to use the "Sortable" option, but to sort on click.
As example, on click, move to top and then open.... ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it has been a while, but I wanted to update fore everyone's benefit.
So for my solution, was simple in the end. Just finding it was the task :-)
First is my JS code using jquery.

```
function contentToggle(v,w,x,y,z) { 
        $('#'+v).slideDown(300);
        $('#'+w).slideUp(20);       
        $('#'+x).slideUp(20);   
        $('#'+y).slideUp(20);   
        $('#'+z).slideUp(20);
}
```

I did split the code in two myself, but this works.

Then on my page I make a link like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:contentToggle('divID_1','divID_2','divID_3','divID_4');">Your link text for divID_1</a>
```

Then repeat.....
But remember what is opening must be first in function line.
Function can be reused, so it is ok to have extra "slide up's" in it for what ever your need is.
Only the ones sent to function will run

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want the accordion effect?

Like this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ?

Comment: Not realy. I want each div to slide down .... never slide up. Sort of like a rotating wheel, but that the order is never the same. The next in line needs to be the selected. Well that is the look I am after.